# Is there anyone using Xbrowser for html or aspx pages testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, unit-testing

There is a requirement for us to implement browser testing for html and aspx pages. I came across xbrowser at the below link.

http://xbrowser.codeplex.com/

I couldn't find any documentation on their website , it has only solution file. I downloaded the code but its not running fully.

Any help or guidence will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XBrowser isn't based on Trident (IE), WebKit (Safari/Chrome), Gecko (Firefox) or any other common rendering engine so as far as "browser testing" its pretty much useless. What it is intended for is website automation. You can instantiate it in code, tell it to navigate to a webpage and then tell it various things such as "enter xyz into the search field and click the submit button". If this is what you're looking for then its also very important to understand that just because what you've tested works in XBrowser doesn't mean it will work anywhere else. It might, it might not, you won't know until you manually test every browser.

If you follow the link at the top of the codeplex site you'll see that the project has been moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/axefrog/XBrowser). From there the author has a link to an earlier project call [SimpleBrowser](https://github.com/axefrog/SimpleBrowser) that has some examples that I imagine are similar to XBrowser.

Comment: thanks for the informatiom , that is what i am exactly looking for , website automation. I went to the xbrowser website but they don't have any examples or documentation there. I will go through SimpleBrowser not , but looks like they don't support jquery or javascript. did you use xbrowser or Simplebrowser in any of your code, can you please provide more guidence on this as i don't have much idea.

Comment: I haven't used it before but I just checked out the version from GitHub and can't seem to be able to do much with it. You can navigate to pages but can't query the DOM yet. The unit tests are failing, too, so I think its a little too early to start using this.